# Compute the convolution of two arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate an array from some starting values using this formula in MATLAB:

> y<sub>t</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>p</sup>  (a<sub>i</sub> ⋅ y<sub>t-i</sub>), t ≥ p

**p** is some small number compared to **T** (max t). I have been able to make this using two `for` cycles but it is really slow. Is there some easy way to do it?

First *p* values of **y** are provided and vector **a** (its length is *p+1*) is provided too...

This is what I have so far, but now when I tried it, it doesn't work 100% (I think it's because of indexing from 1 in MATLAB):

```
y1 = zeros(T+1, 1);
y1(1:p) = y(1:p);

for t = p+1:T+1
    value = a1(1);
    for j = 2:p+1
        value = value + a1(j)*y1(t-j+1);
    end
    y1(t) = value;
end
```

EDIT: I solved it, I am just not used to Matlab indexing from 1...

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.  It's much easier for us to edit what you have than to write it for you.

Comment: RE Latex. Don't try on SO -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow/60020#60020

Comment: Matlab already contains a command for that: see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html Regarding help for your program specify what you mean be "it doesnt work 100%".

Comment: @prapin quote prapin: "Managed to typeset the equation using Unicode characters" - heheheh awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y1 = zeros(T+1, 1);
y1(1:p) = y(1:p);

for t = p+1:T+1
    value = a1(1);
    for j = 2:p+1
        value = value + a1(j)*y1(t-j+1);
    end
    y1(t) = value;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
    if(p>=t)
```

looks odd inside a loop whose index expression is

```
for t = p+1:T+1
```

which seems to guarantee that `t>p` for the entire duration of the loop.  Is that what you meant to write ?

**EDIT** in response to comment

Inside a loop indexed with this statement

```
for j = 2:p
```

how does the reference you make to `a(j)` ever call for `a(0)` ?

Comment: Sorry, i meant something diferent, there was an error in the code (corrected now) - u are absolutely right